# Number_format_Exception

Tags: java, regex, numberformatexception

What makes the difference between these two lines such that it removes the 
run time error in my code

If I used this then I get an error message:

```
int size=Integer.parseInt(br.readline());
```

but if I used below line then it works fine

```
int size=Intger.parseInt(br.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+",""));
```

**Error message is:**

> Runtime ErrorException in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "32363 "
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
>       at Main.main(File.java:17)

Answer (score 2):

Per the [`parseInt()` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-):

> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. **The characters in the string must all be decimal digits**, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.

So even though `.replaceAll("\\s+","")` works for you today, it is not a 100% fool-proof solution for all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

In the first version you parse as string containing whitespaces. In the the error message one is mentioned: `"32363 "`. When you call `br.readLine().replaceAll("\s+","")` all whitespaces are removed (replaced with empty strings to be precise) and you have a string prepared for parsing.

`\s` is a regex character class for whitespace characters and `+` means "repeat once or more times".

Comment: Depending on the nature of the input data br.readLine().trim() might be simpler and more efficient.   The regex method will remove whitespace in the middle of the digits as well... this may lead to undesirable inputs if two numbers were entered on a line separated by whitespace and they were not intended to be treated as a single number.  You may want to catch the problem in that case instead of silently going ahead with an unintended value.